# How do you set the user in a C# application without using impersonation?

Tags: c#, windows-10, impersonation

I would like to run my program as another user. I don't want to run just parts of it as the other user. I want the entire thing to be ran as the other user.

Two ways I've found to do that are

**1.**

```
runas /user:joe "C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolApp\CoolApp.exe"
```

**2.**

```
Process p = new Process("C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolApp\CoolApp.exe");
p.StartInfo.UserName = "joe";
p.StartInfo.Password = "joe-rulz-123";
p.Start();
```

The first way could be just a modified shortcut but requires setting up the password (with the `/savecreds` switch) and I'm a little worried about having to set that up again.

The second way requires launching the program from a separate program which while doable is one extra moving part I don't need.

Using Impersonation is a very popular answer but I need to run the entire application as the user, not just a part of it.

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, username, password, logonType))
{
    // do whatever you want as this user.
}
```

Isn't there a setting in app.config or in the application manifest that will let me hardcode the user?

Comment: You don't need a separate program - If your app starts without a "/blah" command line then have it process.start() itself with /blah & the appropriate user details?

Comment: The user's token (i.e. his security identity) gets attached to the program before any of your code executes.  There's nothing you can do within the program.  An application manifest can change whether or not an application runs with a users normal token or his/her elevated token (if he has one), but I don't believe it can change the user's identity